# Rearranging double integral and bounds

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to figure out why we can rewrite

$\int_0^n s (\int_0^s 1 \, dt) \, ds = \frac{n^3}{3}$

as

$\int_0^n 1 (\int_s^n t \, dt) \, ds = \frac{n^3}{3}$

I would appreciate any pushes in the right direction. I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: With the first integral do you mean $\int_0^n (\int_0^s s \, ds)\, dt$?

Comment: No, I looked over both integrals and they are both what I meant to write. I added parenthesis now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the square with vertices $(0,0),(0,n),(n,0),(n,n)$ in the $st$-plane and let $d$ be the diagonal from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$.

In the first integral you are summing the lengths of the vertical segments from the $s$-axis to $d$ multiplied by their abscissa.

On the other hand, in the second integral you are summing the lengths of the horizontal segments from the $t$-axis to $d$ multiplied by their ordinate.

Do you see that these operations are a mirror copy of each other?